# Is it possible to assign object to int?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a CCounter class which holds and integer value protected by mutex. I've defined several operators like post/pre inc/dec returning an integer so I can do:

```
CCounter c(10);
int i = c++;
```

but what do I do with a simple assignment like `i = c` ? I tried to define friend operator= but it gives me

`operator=(int&, const CCounter&)’ must be a nonstatic member function`

error. Please, advise. Thanks.

Comment: Beside the solutions the others wrote: You should make the return values of your ++/-- operators CCounter &/CCounter and not int!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to define a casting operator that casts from CCounter to int. Add this member to your class:

```
operator int() const {
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: Hi I did this, but I got:  error: cannot convert ‘CircularInt’ to ‘int’ in initialization
     int i = hour; Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Tomer: Unfortunately, I cannot answer your question. What is `CircularInt` and how does your problem relate to my answer? Perhaps you should ask a new question where you describe the details of your problem?

Answer (score 8):

As you have found out, the assignment operator must be a member function of a class. As ints are not classes, you can't write operator=() for them. The alternative, as others have pointed out is to write a function that converts to an int. I would strongly suggest you write a named function like ToInt() to do this, rather than using a conversion operator, which can be the source of non-obvious bugs.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why the operator= can not be used, and for the hint of explicit function. Go further than a code snippet ... (I've done that, shame on me :) )

Comment: And I would recommend him to make the return values of his inc/dec operators CCounter &/CCounter and not int!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `operator int()` to allow the conversion of your class to an int. For example:

```
class CCounter
{
    public:
    CCounter(int val) : m_val(val)
    {
    }

     operator int() const
    {
        return m_val;
    }

    private:
    int m_val;
};





int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    CCounter c(10);
    int n = c;

    std::cout<<n<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

Shouldn't you be defining an accessor function instead if you're just "getting" the current value of the counter?

Something like:

```
int GetCounter();
```

Anything else is sort of disguising the intention of what you're trying to do. IMHO Natch! (-:

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

As said use the int() operator. Here a code snippet :

```
#include <iostream>

class CCounter
{
    public:
    CCounter(int i = 0) : _count(i) {}
    operator int() { return _count; }

    private:
    int _count;

};

int main()
{
    CCounter counter(4);
    int c = counter;
    std::cout << "Counter = " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> "I've defined several operators like post/pre inc/dec returning an integer".

Now that other answers provided you with a generic way to convert the object to an integer, I would recommend that you change these other operators so that they behave as typically expected.

For instance, pre increment typically returns a reference to the object itself, and post increment typically returns a temporary copy of the original object (prior to the incrementation).

```
CCounter& operator++() {
    ++m_val;
    return *this;
}

CCounter operator++(int) {
    CCounter tmp(*this);
    ++m_val;
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have been given [a valid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130440/is-it-possible-to-assign-object-to-int/1130452#1130452), I would also consider simply creating **a normal function which returns int**, such as `int GetValue() const`, to improve readability and ease of maintenance. Of course this is highly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class CA {
public:
    int a;
    CA(int x):a(x)
    {

    }
    operator int() const {
        return a;
    }

    void operator ()() {

    }
};

void main(){

    CA obj = 100;
    int k = obj;
    obj();
}
```