# Implicit conversion from user-defined type to primitive type in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I am able to find plenty of information about implicit conversion from, say, an int to a user defined type.  i.e. if a constructor takes an int as its parameter and is not prefaced by "explicit" then implicit conversions can occur.

What if I want my class to implicitly convert *to* an int?

For example, what function needs to be added either inside or outside of SimpleClass such that the main function will compile and output "1" to the console? (see comments)

```
#include <iostream>

class SimpleClass
{
private:
    int m_int;
public:
    SimpleClass(int value)
    : m_int(value) {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SimpleClass simpleclass(1);
    int i = simpleclass; // does not complile
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // should output "1" to the console
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to assign object to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130440/is-it-possible-to-assign-object-to-int) for the object to int primitive side, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766964/how-can-the-assignment-from-int-to-object-be-possible-in-c for  the other

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implicit conversions can be defined in two ways:

- non-explicit single-argument constructor.
- non-explicit conversion function (a.k.a. conversion operator), N3337 12.3.2

The later allows defining conversion from class type to primitive type. Just add

```
class SimpleClass {
   // ...
   operator int() const;
};

SimpleClass::operator int() const
{
   return m_int;
}
```

Comment: These are **conversions**, not **casts**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: I tested your answer and it is exactly what I was looking for.  My web searches were slightly off so I needed the help.  Thank you for the quick answer @JanHudec.

Comment: @MatthewBriggs: Make sure to read the warnings in Cheers and hth.'s answer too. Cast operators to primitive types are indeed often a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 8):

### The technical.

Conversion to (almost) any type `T` can be performed by an `operator T` member function.

It is by default invoked implicitly, and if you declare it `const` it can also be invoked on a `const` object.

Thus:

```
struct MyType
{
    operator int() const { return 1; }
};
```

### Problems…

Having a an implicit conversion to basic type allows free play for all the built-in operators, including

- Arithmetic operators.
- Boolean operators.
- Relational operators.

So you better make sure that all this *works the way you want*.

And that can be a lot of work!

There are also potential problems with overload resolution for calls involving instances of your type.

In short, implicit conversion to `int`, or pointer, or any built-in type, usually costs more than it's worth.

An exception where it can be worthwhile is when a class is used a lot, in a library.

### What you can do about it.

Avoid implicit conversion, but do offer explicit conversion.

The best general explicit conversion is, IMHO, a named member function.

An alternative is an `operator T` prefixed with the keyword `explicit`, which is supported for this use in C++11 and later (in C++03 it could only be used on constructors).

If you want output via `<<` to behave as if an implicit conversion is performed, then just define an `operator<<`.

And similarly for other situations where an implicit conversion would appear to be a general solution: just define what's appropriate for that specific situation, and avoid introducing a general implicit conversion.

---

To provide implicit conversion to a built-in type and yet avoid the “free for all” for built-in operators, you can use a *templatized type conversion*, e.g. like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class A, class B > struct Is_t_;

template< class Type > struct Is_t_<Type, Type> { using T = void; };

template< class A, class B >
using If_is_ = typename Is_t_<A, B>::T;

struct Bad_string
{
    operator const char* () const { return "666!"; }
    Bad_string( char const* = 0 ) {}
};

auto operator==( Bad_string const&, Bad_string const& )
    -> bool
{ return true; }

struct Good_string
{
    template< class Type, class Enabled_ = If_is_<const char*, Type>>
    operator Type() const { return "42 :)"; }

    Good_string( char const* = 0 ) {}
};

auto operator==( Good_string const&, Good_string const& )
    -> bool
{ return true; }

#if defined( DO_GOOD )
    using String = Good_string;
#elif defined( DO_BAD )
    using String = Bad_string;
#else
#   error "Define either DO_GOOD or DO_BAD, please."
#endif

auto main() -> int
{
    String a, b;
    (void) (a == "alfalfa");        // Errs for Bad_string
    (void) (a + 1);                 // Compiles for Bad_string.
}
```

Ironically, when `DO_GOOD` is defined this code [crashes the Visual C++ 2015 update 1 compiler](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2163090/internal-compiler-error-on-some-sfinae-code), a so called “ICE” (Internal Compiler Error).

A workaround for that compiler is to instead define `If_is_` as

```
template< class A, class B >
using If_is_ = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<A, B>::value >;
```

Comment: Thank you for the warning.  Now that I know how to do it, I'm not sure that I want to.

Comment: +1 for  succinct yet comprehensive summary, especially "Having a an implicit conversion to basic type allows free play for all the built-in operators" - I get the impression people forget this - when asking _and_ answering! In my case, I want this to happen, but I can imagine it's a real pain for other user types. This neat summary is really useful.

Comment: @underscore_d: Somehow I omitted a technique that I sometimes use to avoid the "free play" yet have an implicit conversion, namely to templatize the conversion operator on the return type, and use SFINAE enabling (e.g. `std::enable_if_t`) for just the type or types I want to support. But then, maybe it's too complex to post as general advice.

Comment: Added example of the omitted technique.

Comment: Cool! Is there a standard passage regarding the 'free for all' effect? I'm trying to absorb as much authoritative info on this as I can. I recently got caught out by how defining both an `operator BasicType()` and `operator=(BasicType)` didn't 'mask' the implicit `operator=(ThisType)`... which if not directly related, still indicates the perils of using intuition when it comes to implicit conversions!

Comment: This is amazing! Could you explain why templatizing the conversion function fixes the "free for all" problem?

Answer (score 1):

To allow your class to be converted to an `int`, implement

```
operator int() const
{
  return m_int;
}
```